# Кодировка страниц на сервере denwer

Tags: кодировка, html, denwer

Добрый день! Возникла следующая проблема с кодировкой страниц. Скачал шаблон сайта в формате html в котором была указана кодировка utf-8 (в разделе META).

При просмотре страницы через браузер все отлично выводит текст на русском. Проблема возникает, когда я кидаю этот файл на локальный сервер denwer. Вместо текста выводится абракадабра. На платном хостинге этот файл отображается нормально [Страничка в сети](http://book-fan.ru/).

Как добиться того чтобы текст отображался нормально на денвере с кодировкой utf-8?

**Примечание:** *В дальнейшем планирую выводить страницы и данные из базы данных в формате utf-8, без лишней перекодировки.*

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Добавить** в `.htaccess` такую строчку:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Для **всего сервера** можно в `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` заменить

```
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
```

на

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую...

Comment: Помогло)))